# Align different sized Images that do not have parent container

Tags: html, css

**My Issue:** How can I "center" the images so the Headers left-align looks clean?

[image: I just realized (late in a project) that the icons that were uploaded in a list style s]

I just realized I didn't plan for different sized icons on a site, and I'm wondering if there's a quick, **non-hacky** solution. *I won't be able to edit the HTML in any way due to the size of the project*.

*I'm okay with `Psudeo` and `calc` solutions*

edit: *Setting a fixed width causes noticable blurring on the site and/or makes taller icons too small*

**jsFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/vantbrhb/

Comment: You could just give them a fixed size and height. If they are all roughly same size there shouldn't be much stretching or anything. http://jsfiddle.net/vantbrhb/1/

Comment: On the live site, the blurring is decently noticeable

Comment: Gotcha. Wasn't sure. Def do not want that! Sorry.

Comment: Quite alright! I appreciate effort

Comment: So is it safe to say you cannot change any of the HTML?

Comment: I can, but I ruled it out in the original post because it would take a really long time

Comment: OK because if you can change them, then making them divs and setting images as background urls opens you to more options like using background-size style property. The cover or contain value might be what helps. http://jsfiddle.net/vantbrhb/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give `position:absolute;` to the `h5` and then align it to the `left` side;

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/vantbrhb/4/)

Comment: Updated my initial question to include span. I noted that I wouldn't be able to wrap it in a div, but I should've said I couldn't wrap it in general

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding this class and take a look at how the images display:

```
.content img {
     width: 55px;   
}
```

Comment: Though this would fix the issue, it cause would cause the images to pixelate :/ *+1 though since you are right in a way*

Answer (score 2):

I didn't realize you couldn't modify the HTML - ignore my last post. Here is a pseudo selector that should select each image based on the "src". Hope 3rd times the charm:

```
img[src*="placehold.it/50x50"] {
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
img[src*="placehold.it/55x49"] {
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
}
img[src*="placehold.it/48x52"] {
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 6px;
}
img[src*="placehold.it/50x54"] {
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Not a bad idea! Definitely considering this as a fallback!!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the border and padding from `img`, and add these styles:

```
.content {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;             /*prevent tall lines from overflowing containers */
}

.content h5 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 70px;                   /*wider than your widest image */
  top: 50%;                     /*center vertically            */
  transform: translateY(-50%);  /*  "        "                 */
}

.content h5:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 1000px;               /*really tall!         */
  top: -500px;
  left: -5px;                   /*for a little padding */
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oeyekLty/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using some simple javascript like this:

```
function getWidth(){
var width1 = document.getElementById('img1').offsetWidth;
var width2 = document.getElementById('img2').offsetWidth;
var width3 = document.getElementById('img3').offsetWidth;
var width4 = document.getElementById('img4').offsetWidth;
width1 = 70 - width1;
width2 = 70 - width2;
width3 = 70 - width3;
width4 = 70 - width4;
document.getElementById('img1').style.paddingRight = width1 + "px";
document.getElementById('img2').style.paddingRight = width2 + "px";
document.getElementById('img3').style.paddingRight = width3 + "px";
document.getElementById('img4').style.paddingRight = width4 + "px";
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vantbrhb/6/

Answer (score 1):

The code isn't beautiful but if you can add an ID of #img1, img2, #img3 and #img4 to each img, then the following code should do the trick:

```
#img1 {
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
#img2 {
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
}
#img3 {
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 6px;
}
#img4 {
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Updated my original question. I originally wrote that I couldn't wrap them in divs, but I really can't modify the HTML due to how many icons there are. Sorry I don't communicate that sooner

Comment: Okay, sorry about that - this time I think I have a solution though!

Answer (score 1):

You could do the CSS table layout, it would be better to wrap the `img` into `span` or so, but it still works without doing that.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfLngw5t/)**

```css
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 1px;
}
.content {
    display: table-row;
    background: pink;
}
img, h5 {
    margin: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
    padding-right: 5px;
}
h5 {
    width: 100%;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
        <h5>Header 1</h5>
    </div>
    
    <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/55x49" />
        <h5>Header 2</h5>
    </div>
    
    <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/48x52" />
        <h5>Header 3</h5>
    </div>
    
    <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x54" />
        <h5>Header 4</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```